# SQL Server Conversion Failure when using INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I have an existing table full of data, which can be created using

```
CREATE TABLE __EpisodeCost
(
    ActivityRecordID INT NOT NULL, 
    ActCstID NVARCHAR(15), 
    VolAmt FLOAT, 
    ActCnt FLOAT, 
    TotCst FLOAT, 
    ResCstID NVARCHAR(50)
);
```

This comes from a feed I have no control over and I want to convert this to my own version called `EpisodeCost`

```
CREATE TABLE EpisodeCostCtp
(
    ActivityRecordID INT NOT NULL, 
    ActCstID NVARCHAR(6), 
    ResCstID NVARCHAR(7), 
    ActCnt NVARCHAR(7), 
    TotCst DECIMAL(18, 8) 
);
```

Now, the problem I am having is with conversions. I can execute the query

```
SELECT 
    ActivityRecordID, 
    Cast(ActCstID AS NVARCHAR(6)), 
    Cast(ResCstID AS NVARCHAR(7)), 
    Cast(LTRIM(STR(ActCnt, 10)) AS NVARCHAR(7)), 
    Cast(TotCst AS DECIMAL(18, 8)) 
FROM __EpisodeCostCtp;
```

and it provides data, however, when I try to execute

```
INSERT INTO EpisodeCostCtp 
    (
        ActivityRecordID, 
        ActCstID, 
        ResCstID, 
        ActCnt, 
        TotCst 
    ) 
SELECT 
    ActivityRecordID, 
    Cast(ActCstID AS NVARCHAR(6)), 
    Cast(ResCstID AS NVARCHAR(7)), 
    Cast(LTRIM(STR(ActCnt, 10)) AS NVARCHAR(7)), 
    Cast(TotCst AS DECIMAL(18, 8)) 
FROM __EpisodeCostCtp;
```

I get

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 102
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Why can I `SELECT` using the relevant casts, but then cannot `INSERT` into the target table?

---

Edit. I still don;t fully know what is occurring here.

As per Serg's recommendations, I have attempted to locate the problematic records but the query

```
SELECT 
    ActivityRecordID, 
    Cast(ActCstID AS NVARCHAR(6)), 
    Cast(ResCstID AS NVARCHAR(7)), 
    Cast(LTRIM(STR(ActCnt, 10)) AS NVARCHAR(7)), 
    Cast(TotCst AS DECIMAL(18, 8))      
FROM __EpisodeCostCtp
WHERE TotCst > 9.999999999999999e9;
```

returns zero records. Changing to 9.999999999999999e8 does, and the conversion/cast happens with out error. I have scince changed the `INSERT` query to use `DECIMAL(36, 18)` and now the insert succeeds, but I am still none the wiser. Clearly I was hitting a limit on the cast, but why `SELECT` works and `INSERT` fails, I still don't know.

Comment: Any significance in the fact that you introduce the table as `__EpisodeCost` and then show two queries querying `__EpisodeCostCtp`?

Comment: You don't have any triggers on target table?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no, at this point there are no PK/FKs on either table. This is as simple as it gets, select data from one table into another of a slightly different format. No triggers on either table.

Comment: Could you try using [`SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-numeric-roundabort-transact-sql) before `INSERT`: `SET ... OFF; INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM...;` ?

Comment: Could you show some sample data please that generates this issue? (ideally as an insert statement)? I tried it with dummy data and it worked fine.

Comment: What is the max length of TotCst in First Table, you are casting it as 18,8. Might return error if the precedence length is > 18

Comment: I have tried using `SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;` and this did not help - same message. @JeffUK, the problem is, I can't tell which data is causing the problem as it only occurs with the insert statement. I will see if I can investigate further...

Comment: Have you tried a subset of the data? I.e set a where clause, or use TOP... and see if it works? Maybe that will help narrow it down. In fact, if you incrementally increase TOP X, you will be able to identify  a sample that fails very easily.

Comment: If you execute SELECT in a tool like SSMS then  a parameter which limits a number of rows returned may apply and error is not thrown.

Comment: @Serg I didn't think this was the case with SQL MS. Any reference as this would be very interesting to know...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180280(v=sql.120).aspx SET ROWCOUNT  option. It's rarely ever set, but check it to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for these comment guys. The one that stands out is @Serg's which seems to suggest that the `SELECT` might only be selecting a sub-set of the data. This could be the problem. I am going to try and do this with a truly massive decimal cast `DECIMAL(36, 18)` and see what happens. Perhaps I should have done this before, but I wasn't aware `SELECT` only selects a sub-set of the data - is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as is an overflow issue you might want to try

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql

> When an INSERT statement encounters an arithmetic error (overflow,
>   divide by zero, or a domain error) occurring during expression
>   evaluation, the Database Engine handles these errors as if SET
>   ARITHABORT is set to ON. The batch is stopped, and an error message is
>   returned. During expression evaluation when SET ARITHABORT and SET
>   ANSI_WARNINGS are OFF, if an INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE statement
>   encounters an arithmetic error, overflow, divide-by-zero, or a domain
>   error, SQL Server inserts or updates a NULL value. If the target
>   column is not nullable, the insert or update action fails and the user
>   receives an error.

Comment: Nice, I did not know this.

Comment: This has allowed me to get around the problem. What @Serg said above seems to be correct though. SELECT is not acting on all records.

Comment: it might be a case that ArithAbort  and ansi_warnings are off by default. You can check that on SSMS, or just set both to on before the Select statement and try it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your TotCst column has values bigger than DECIMAL(18,8).
And the version 2008 of SQL SERVER gets a rounded result if the destination type is not large enough. But it can't insert because the table accepts exact values only.

You can see the result of my two queries on SQL SERVER 2012 :

```
 DECLARE @float FLOAT 
 SET @float = 12345678911.12
 SELECT CAST(@float AS decimal(18,8))
```

Result :
An arithmetic overflow error occurred when converting float to numeric data type.

the same query with DECIMAL(19,8) instead :

```
 DECLARE @float FLOAT 
 SET @float = 12345678911.12
 SELECT CAST(@float AS decimal(19,8))
```

Result : 12345678911.12000100

EDIT : Check if your query tool fetchs all records. If not, maybe among the rest of records there are some values bigger than DECIMAL(18.8)

Comment: Would OP get the error when he runs the 'select' statement on it's own if this was the case?

Comment: Normally yes. But there is something weird. I will try this on SQL SERVER 2008.

Answer (score 0):

To find rows which cause the problem try

```
SELECT *       
FROM __EpisodeCostCtp
WHERE TotCst > 9.999999999999999e9;
```